# How can I make my Django API only accept requests that come from my website itself?

Tags: javascript, python, django, security, django-rest-framework

I had to create an API for my Django application for something sensitive that I couldn't have in a public and static Javascript file. **How can I make it so that this view only accepts requests coming from my own website, and reject any from the "outside" (if someone copied my request below they should get an error)?**

If there are any other security concerns please do mention them in your response. My website is hosted on Heroku.

The request in my javascript file:

```
var clientSecret = await fetch('https://url.com/api/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: params,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      },
}).then(r => r.json())
```

My view for my API (`https://url.com/api/`):

```
from rest_framework.request import Request as RESTRequest
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import requests

@api_view(['POST'])
def payment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ... #define headers_in and params_in here
    response = requests.post('https://outboundapirequest.com/v1/request', 
            headers=headers_in,
            data=params_in)

    return Response(response.json()['value'])
```

Comment: where are your authentication and permission classes. use drf token to verify requests

Comment: I don't require authentication on my website. This request is part of a script that processes payments, which is why I would only like for me to be able to call the view from the js script I shared and for it to not be possible for someone to make a call to my API endpoint. @I'mSRJ

Comment: you can pass token in your script then

Comment: could you explain what you mean by token? I don't think I have any tokens I've created so far

Comment: @I'mSRJ I guess a better question is how can I create a drf token that is not based on users since I don't have a "Users" model or system?

Comment: create admin(superuser) token and use that one

Comment: @I'mSRJ how would I access that token to pass it into get_context_data for my class based view so that it will be accessible on my HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

By using ‘’cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)’’

In Django settings you can set a list of all domains where requests to your API server are allowed to originate.

Like so

`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ "http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:9000" ]`

[Here is a detailed reference on how to set it up](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-cors-guide/)

Comment: Hi @theseeker, just to clarify once I enable this would anyone trying to make a POST request to my endpoint be rejected? I made the changes in the detailed reference, but it's currently not rejecting me from an online compiler and want to know if this behavior is unexpected.